# Telegram channel- how to get access_hash?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I try really hard to understand howto use Telegram api with telethon. I have some Channels in Telegram, where i want to delete older Messages. Using inputpeerchannel() i need channel_id (No Problem) and channel_hash. I cant findout howto get this channel_hash by channel_id. Thank you from germany

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Can anyone share an updated solution please?

Answer (score 11):

In order to find channel `access_hash`, you should resolve channel username. Original MTProto method `contacts.resolveUsername#f93ccba3` gets @username and returns channel info including `access_hash`.

In telethon you need to invoke [ResolveUsernameRequest](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/contacts/resolve_username.html) to call the above original MTProto method. You may use this code to resolve username to `access_hash`:

```
client = TelegramClient(session_file, api_id=00000, api_hash='XXXXX')
client.connect()
response = client.invoke(ResolveUsernameRequest("your_channel_id"))
print(response.chats[0].access_hash)
client.disconnect()
```

Comment: "your_channel_id" is the username or the channel_id? it does not work for me with the channel_id, it works with the username but I only have the channel_id

Comment: "your_channel_id" is a string and it's the username. You can't access a channel only by `channel_id`. You need `access_hash` too.

Comment: Do you know if the access_hash will be expired?

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways to get access hash:

1. From a Group
2. From username
3. From contact list
4. From chats message

So, if you have id only, there is no way to get access hash

Comment: but where is this user_hash?

Comment: You need to use the method provide by telegram, after that you get an object containing information about ID, Access_Hash, Name,...

Comment: Could you clarify how exactly is possible to get access_hash from a group?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. replace appid, apphash and username

```
with TelegramClient('session.session', <app-id>,<app-hash>') as client:
result = client(functions.contacts.ResolveUsernameRequest(
    username=<username>
))
print(result.stringify())
```